# μ is sigma-finite measure on the Borel sets B(R) .

Tags: real-analysis, probability

$\mu$ is  sigma-finite measure on the Borel sets $\bigl(\Bbb R,\mathcal{B}(\Bbb R)\bigr)$ , define $A$  is any collection of all $A$ in $\mathcal{B}(\Bbb R)$ such that the following limit exists and is finite, 
$$(D\mu)(A) = \lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{\mu\bigl(A\cap[-n, n]\bigr)}{n}.$$
is A an algebra?

Answer (score 1):

I believe the answer is "no" even when $\mu$ is the counting measure on $\mathbb N$.

That is: there are two sets $A, B \subset \mathbb N$
such that natural density exists for $A$ and for $B$, 
but not for $A \cap B$.  That is:
$$
\lim_n\frac{|A \cap \{1,2,\dots,n\}|}{n}\qquad\text{and}\qquad
\lim_n\frac{|B \cap \{1,2,\dots,n\}|}{n}
$$
both exist, but
$$
\lim_n\frac{|A \cap B \cap \{1,2,\dots,n\}|}{n}
$$
does not exist.

**added**

An example goes like this.
Let $A$ be the even numbers.
Choose a sequence $r_m$ increasing rapidly, like $4^m$ or $m!$.
And for $B$ take

even numbers between $r_1$ and $r_2$,
odd numbers between $r_2$ and $r_3$,
even numbers between $r_3$ and $r_4$,
odd numbers between $r_4$ and $r_5$,
even numbers between $r_5$ and $r_6$,
odd numbers between $r_6$ and $r_7$,
and so on.

**added**
OK let's take the example with $r_m = 4^m$.  Write
$$
\lambda_n(E) = \frac{|E \cap \{1,2,\dots,n\}|}{n}
$$
for any set $E$ and $n = 1, 2, 3, \dots$.

First note that $\lambda_{2n}(A) = \frac{n}{2n} = \frac{1}{2}$ and
$\lambda_{2n+1}(A) = \frac{n}{2n+1}$ so in both cases
$|\lambda_n(A) - \frac{1}{2}| < \frac{1}{n}$, and thus $\lambda_n(A) \to \frac{1}{2}$.  Similarly, $\lambda_{2n}(B) = \frac{n}{2n}$ and $\lambda_{2n+1}(B)$ is either $\frac{n}{2n+1}$ or $\frac{n+1}{2n+1}$.  So still
for all $n$, we have $|\lambda_n(B) - \frac{1}{2}|<\frac{1}{n}$, and $\lambda_n(B)$ converges to $\frac{1}{2}$.

Now what about the intersection $A \cap B$?  We will estimate
$\lambda_{4^m}(A \cap B)$ taking the cases $m$ even and $m$ odd.

For $m$ even, we have
$A \cap (4^{m-1},4^m] = B \cap (4^{m-1},4^m]$ is the set of all even
numbers in $(4^{m-1},4^m]$.  There are $\frac{3}{2}\cdot 4^{m-1}$ even numbers in that inverval.  So
$$
\lambda_{3^m}(A \cap B) \ge \frac{ \frac{3}{2}\cdot 4^{m-1}}{4^m} = \frac{3}{8} .
$$

Now consider $m$ odd.  Then
$A \cap B \cap (4^{m-1},4^m]$ is empty, since no number is both even and odd.  Thus
$$
\lambda_{4^m}(A \cap B) \le \frac{|A \cap \{1,2,\dots,4^{m-1}\}|}{4^m}
= \frac{\frac{1}{2} 4^{m-1}}{4^m} = \frac{1}{8} .  
$$

The sequence $\lambda_n(A \cap B)$ has a subsequence ${}\ge \frac{3}{8}$ and another subsequence ${} \le \frac{1}{8}$.  So
$\lambda_n(A\cap B)$ does not converge.

Comment: yes , you are right, but i need specific example for A and B. if A=2Z, OR A=U(2i,2i+1] i want an example for B.

Comment: your example is not clear, why you choose B like that, can you explain that.